# DOMPDF with css float

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I am not sure why but the html page displays just fine but the dompdf does not utilize the floats.

Code is 2300 + line long so to long to post here.... But it is all inline css.

```
<div style="float:left;"> </div>
```

I have tried both wrapping the css in a style tag and inline with no luck.

This is the html page

http://www.ems-complete.com/ccems/ccems_reports/daily_vehicle_check_sheet.php?id=5

This is the dompdf link

http://www.ems-complete.com/ccems/ccems_reports/form_daily_vehicle_check.php?id=5

I am not sure why but the html page displays just fine but the dompdf does not utilize the floats...

Code is 2300 + line long so to long to post here.... But it is all inline css...

Comment: Seems to be missing an `=`?

Answer (score 18):

Float support is introduced in the 0.6.0 code base, but it is disabled by default since it is still in development. Make sure you have enabled it by setting DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT to true.

Starting with version 0.7.0 float support is enabled by default.

That being said, since the feature is still in development you're not going to get the results you want. Floats that span more than one page don't currently work as expected because a page break occurs before the non-floated content is rendered.

Comment: I have already set the float command to true prior to posting this... Plus I have put in a page break to help prevent the floats from spanning more than on page... Is there any Ideal when this function will be functional

Comment: Right now, no. We had hoped to have float support completed for the 0.6.0 final release, but it looks like it will probably slip to the next release. Unfortunately we're a small team with limited resources and I don't see the pace of development increasing in the near future.

Comment: FYI, one of the issues you're seeing is because dompdf doesn't currently size a div to its content on float. So the width is still at 100% for your floated divs. If you specify a width for each column (say 25%) you'll get better results, but the layout is still complicated by the floats being larger than a single page.

Comment: Awesome I will do some Tinkering with it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I added some css width:25%; to the columns and now I get this error Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given, called in /home/emscompl/public_html/ccems/ccems_reports/dompdf/include/table_frame_decorator.cls.php on line 304 and defined in /home/emscompl/public_html/ccems/ccems_reports/dompdf/include/frame.cls.php on line 726

Comment: and now cant get it to clear even when taking these css values out

Comment: Are you using 0.6.0 beta 3 or the latest code from github. I would recommend the latter, if possible.

Comment: Seems I had a missing tag... I am using 0.6.0 I will look at getting the github code now.... But I have done some changes in the css and starting to make head way... check out the link above if you like

Comment: Ah, nice! Glad you're making progress. Wish I had time to help you hack at it, but if you run into a wall let me know.

Comment: Assuming this is the correct address to get the github https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: That is correct. You'll have to download php-font-lib separately from https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib

Comment: it tried with 0.8.5 but still not working with float

Answer (score 13):

Guys use **display: inline-block;** instead of float. I use the older version of dompdf in my project. I enable DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT true in dompdf_config.custom.inc file. But the float result is overlapping and distorted.The inline-block is the new and better way than using float left every time. Visit the following w3school link to more info. [CSS Layout - inline-block](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)

Comment: *ding ding ding* we have a winner!

Answer (score 6):

use def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT", true);  in dompdf_config.inc.php

it works for your css float

Answer (score 2):

you need use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
is the plugin `dompdf` for **Laravel 5**.

and change the config in:

vendor/barrryvdh/laravel-dompdf/config/dompdf.php

```
def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT", true);
```

Comment: laravel-dompdf 0.6.1 doesn't seem to handle the bootstrap `.col-xs-X` grid styles very well, so I just forced them to `display: inline-block` instead and changed the widths to squeeze them in with the `@media print` layout.

Comment: Do not change in vendor folder! When you'll do a composer update this change will be gone. Bad practice. Publish the config first.

Answer (score 1):

use `<div style="position: absolute; left: 6px;"></div>` in my case

```
def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_CSS_FLOAT", true);
```

is Not Working